# Create TransactionScope and Create Context order

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity, transactionscope

What is difference of these codes:

```
using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope ())
{
     using (Entities ent = new Entities())
     {
```

and

```
using (Entities ent = new Entities())
{
    using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope ())
    {
```

Does line order matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it wouldn't matter, since the `Entities` seems like Model / Data class, which cannot / needn't enlist into a transaction, so you can have any order, it would not create a difference. Now if the there's any issue in the `Entities` operation, Read / DML then transaction would also abort, assuming that operation takes place in the ambient transaction context, though class / object doing it like `IDBConnection` would anyway automatically enlisted into a transaction (provided not set to false), however even if Connection is created outside transaction context, then would not automatically enlist, needs explicit enlisting for Transaction Context

> In Short

For your current code, it doesn't matter till the point you are dealing with an object that needs Transaction enlistment like `IDBConnection`. **Out of two code snippets though my preference would be first one, where ambient transaction is all encompassing all the objects need to be enlist automatically does, we don't leave any object by chance.**

> Important Difference

What you though may want to be careful about whether you want to access Entities outside the Transaction Context, since that is not possible in the **Option 1 but would not be an issue in the Option 2**

Comment: Thanks But why did you say that my Model did not need enlist in to transaction? I want to use transaction with y entities

Comment: Model doesn't Enlist like `Class Employee` doesn't enlist but object like `DBConnection` or `DBContext` enlist, they are the one which work on the models and do transaction operations, this needs to be differentiated

Answer (score 1):

Yes the order matters.  Or rather we can't say it doesn't matter without looking at your code.

DbConnection instances will enist in an ambient transaction if one exists when they are Open()ed.

Your DbContext constructor might open the underlying DbConnection, in which case the two patterns differ.

The first one is the normal pattern, and you should stick to that.

Also if you are using SQL Server don't use the default constructor of TransactionScope.  See [Using new TransactionScope() Considered Harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful/)